# For $a>0,b>0,c>0$, prove $\frac{a(a^2+bc)}{b+c}+\frac{b(b^2+ca)}{bc+a}+\frac{c(c^2+ab)}{a+b}\geq ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

Suppose $a>0,b>0,c>0$, prove
$$\frac{a(a^2+bc)}{b+c}+\frac{b(b^2+ca)}{c+a}+\frac{c(c^2+ab)}{a+b}\geq ab+bc+ca.$$
Any help will welcome!
This problem is from a competition. I just hope someone can give me some hints to start this problem!
I begin this with 
$$\frac{a^3}{a+b}+\frac{b^3}{b+c}+\frac{c^3}{c+a}\geq \frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}.$$
But it seems no use for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to
$$\frac{(a+b+c)(a^4+b^4+c^4-a^2b^2-b^2c^2-c^2a^2)}{(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)}\geq 0$$
Now just use that $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$ for all real $x,y,z$ is hold.

Comment: Can you say more how to get your inequality?  Reduction of fractions to common denominator??

Comment: Yes that is what i did and moving all Terms to the left.

Comment: Should i post one more step for your control?

Comment: That will be nice!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3+abc}{b+c}-ab-ac-bc=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3+abc}{b+c}-\frac{a(b+c)}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(2a^2-b^2-c^2)}{2(b+c)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a((a-b)(a+b)-(c-a)(a+c))}{2(b+c)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a(a+b)}{2(b+c)}-\frac{b(a+b)}{2(a+c)}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(a+b)(a+b+c)}{2(a+c)(b+c)}\geq0.$$